# What Free 2D CAD programs can export to Blender?

Tags: export

I find it very difficult to use curves in blender. I used to use Corel Draw X4 but it does not work on windows 10. Is there a free program which I could use for 2D drawings which could then be exported to blender ?

Comment: InkScape, but this is not Blender related question.

Comment: I'll be using the CAD program purely for exporting to blender so I thought that would be appropriate here. I'm still kind of new to stackexchange so excuse me if I'm not well aware yet!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Blender as defined in the help center.

Comment: Any program that can save vector (paths or curves) information as SVG or DXF (you'll need to enable a plugin to use the latter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand anything that will export/save 'SVG' files. SVG can be imported into Blender. There's quite a few questions about how Blender treats SVG in here.

An SVG option under save/export has rapidly become fairly standard for most vector drafting applications. I'm not up on the free stuff right now, so I'm afraid you'll need to do the leg work to find out which one's will save SVG files. Hope this helps.